# Codeigniter Datamapper ORM php 7 static issue

Tags: codeigniter, orm, datamapper

When I upgraded my server to php7 codeigniter and in particular datamapper ORM gives me this error...

> Message: Accessing static property DataMapper::$config as non static
>   Filename: libraries/datamapper.php  Line Number: 6474

the function in question is...

```
protected function _dmz_assign_libraries()
{
    static $CI;
    if ($CI || $CI =& get_instance())
    {
        // make sure these exists to not trip __get()
        $this->load = NULL;
        $this->config = NULL;
        $this->lang = NULL;
        // access to the loader
        $this->load =& $CI->load;
        // to the config
        $this->config =& $CI->config;
        // and the language class
        $this->lang =& $CI->lang;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I have the same problem. To fix it, try to add new protected static method

```
protected static function get_config_object() {
    $CI =& get_instance();

    return $CI->config;
}
```

then delete or comment the lines 6474 and 6481 (in `_dmz_assign_libraries`, where values are assigned to `$this->config`),

and finally replace all calls `$this->config` with `self::get_config_object()`

It should run correctly now.

Answer (score 3):

Try to suppress error with @, eg:

```
@$this->config =& $CI->config;
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.

FIX: **Replace the actual datamapper.php library version with the latest one.**

As mentioned in the [official library website](https://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/)

Latest library version (1.8.3-dev) - source: https://github.com/saekort/datamapper/blob/master/application/libraries/datamapper.php